# Expanding each element in a (2-by-2) matrix to a (3-by-2) block

Tags: matlab, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I want to expand each element in a (2-by-2) matrix to a (3-by-2) block, using Python 3 --- with professional and elegant codes. Since I don't know the python codes, I will just describe the following in maths

```
X =              # X is an 2-by-2 matrix.
     1, 2
     3, 4

d = (3,2)        # d is the shape that each element in X should be expanded to.
Y =              # Y is the result
     1, 1, 2, 2
     1, 1, 2, 2
     1, 1, 2, 2
     3, 3, 4, 4
     3, 3, 4, 4
     3, 3, 4, 4
```

Not that every element in X is now an 3-by-2 block in Y. The position of the block in Y is the same as the position of the element in X.

Here is the MATLAB code

```
X = [1,2;3,4];
d = [3,2]
[row, column] = size(X);
a = num2cell(X);
b = cell(row, column);
[b{:}] = deal(ones(d));

Y = cell2mat(cellfun(@times,a,b,'UniformOutput',false));
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is X `[[1,2],[3,4]]` or `[[1,3],[2,4]]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are okay with using [`NumPy module`](http://www.numpy.org/) with Python, you can use [`numpy.kron`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html) -

```
np.kron(X,np.ones((3,2),dtype=int))
```

Sample run -

```
In [15]: import numpy as np

In [16]: X = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)+1 # Create input array

In [17]: X
Out[17]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [18]: np.kron(X,np.ones((3,2),dtype=int))
Out[18]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

In fact, this is a direct translation of how one would achieved the desired result in `MATLAB` in an *elegant and professional way* as well, as shown below -

```
>> X = [1,2;3 4]
X =
     1     2
     3     4
>> kron(X,ones(3,2))
ans =
     1     1     2     2
     1     1     2     2
     1     1     2     2
     3     3     4     4
     3     3     4     4
     3     3     4     4
```

Comment: This is great, it solves completely my question. Thanks.

Comment: @percusse That was meant abit for humor to resemble the `professional` part mentioned in the question. So, please don't read into it seriously :)

Comment: @Divakar Ah OK, it was just a curiosity :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it with [`ndarray.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.repeat.html):

```
>>> X = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)+1
>>> X.repeat(3, axis=0).repeat(2, axis=1)
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

Comment: I think this is the more idiomatic approach.  `numpy.repeat` is designed explicitly for this task.  `numpy.kron` can do it, but I think it is a less direct approach.

Comment: Also note that you can do `np.arange(1, 5)`