# Array Expansion in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array, say:

```
 [a b c d
  e f g h
  i j k l]
```

And I would like to expand the array as follows for size n=2  square expansion of each element:

```
 [[a a  [b b  [c c  [d d
   a a]  b b]  c c]  d d]
  [e e  [f f   ... ]
   e e]  f f]
```

Or n=3

```
 [[a a a   ... 
   a a a 
   a a a] 
      :
      .
```

I have no idea where to start and I hope to stick to basic packages like numpy but whatever is easiest. Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Are these arrays or matrices?

Comment: I think you have 2-D matrix at the start, i.e. `[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], [ 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l]]`. Isn't it?
`

Comment: It's a multidimensional array so I guess a matrix

Comment: @moinuddin quadri That is correct

Comment: Is it an array of numbers or strings?

Comment: @Divakar They are numbers

Comment: @SterlingButters Please correct the question. And also update the expected output. Currently it is confusing. By `[a a [ b b ..]]` do you mean, `['aa', ['bb', ..]]` OR, `['a', 'a', ['b', 'b'..]]`

Comment: See if this helps out - [`Expanding each element in a (2-by-2) matrix to a (3-by-2) block`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051676/expanding-each-element-in-a-2-by-2-matrix-to-a-3-by-2-block).

Comment: The kron function is exactly what I need, thank you Divakar

Answer (score 0):

So consider this:

```
x = []
y = []
xpart = []
ypart = []

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        xpart.append(0)
        ypart.append(0)
    x.append(xpart)
    y.append(ypart)
    xpart = []
    ypart = []
x[0] = y
print(x[1])
```

I start with an array (x) that is 5x5.  Then I assign the first element of that array to be a whole new array.